# How do I return different column values into one?

Tags: join

How would I achieve the desired tables? I want to ensure that I include all of the names mentioned in both Table A & B.

TABLE A

| Name | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | Blue |
| Abe | Green |
| Diane | Red |

TABLE B

| Name | Fruit |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | Apple |
| Abe | Banana |
| Jack | Kiwi |

DESIRED TABLE 1

| Name | Interests |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | Blue |
| Mike | Apple |
| Abe | Green |
| Abe | Banana |
| Diane | Red |
| Jack | Kiwi |

DESIRED TABLE 2

| Name | Color | Fruit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | Blue |  |
| Mike |  | Apple |
| Abe | Green |  |
| Abe |  | Banana |
| Diane | Red |  |
| Jack |  | Kiwi |

I joined Table A and Table B on Name but my results are only showing the names for Table A. It is excluding Jack.

I wouldn't mind either desired tables. Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is count the number of unique names when joining both tables. My result should be 4 (for Mike, Abe, Diane, Jack).

Comment: What's the system you're using? MySQL, PostgreSQL, MS SQL, something else?

Answer (score 0):

For desired table 1 (all the data in two columns), `UNION` of two queries would do. For example

```
SELECT
    Name,
    Color as Interests
FROM TableA
UNION
SELECT
    Name,
    Fruit as Interests
FROM TableB
ORDER BY Name ASC
```

For a variation on desired table 2 (all the data in three colums), you ***might*** be able do it with 'FULL JOIN'.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(
        TableA.Name,
        TableB.Name
    ) AS Name,
    COALESCE (
        TableA.Color,
        ""
    ) AS Color,
    COALESCE (
        TableB.Fruit,
        ""
    ) AS Fruit
FROM TableA
FULL JOIN TableB
    ON TableA.Name = TableB.Name
ORDER BY Name ASC
```

A couple of explanations for this query:

- the output is a variation of what you said you wanted. A variation, because it might not return multiple rows per name - color - fruit combo, just one. Might not - in case the names are unique in the tables you're joining. If you have multiple people named Mike, then this query will return multiple row combos. For instance, using this query on the following two tables

| Name | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Barney | Purple |
| Barney | Blue |

| Name | Fruit |
| --- | --- |
| Barney | Apple |
| Barney | Pear |
| Barney | Orange |

will result in something like this

| Name | Color | Fruit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Barney | Purple | Apple |
| Barney | Blue | Apple |
| Barney | Purple | Pear |
| Barney | Blue | Pear |
| Barney | Purple | Orange |
| Barney | Blue | Orange |

In both cases (single name - color - fruit combo, multiple name - color - fruit combos), the only time you will get an empty value for `Color` or `Fruit` is when a name is present in just one of the two tables

- `COALESCE` is used because the `Name` might exist in the second table, and not in the first one, and we want to make sure that the name and corresponding property are present in the result of the query. The other property (the one missing) is, in that case, represented by an empty character
- for the same reason, we're using a `FULL JOIN` - we want to make sure we get all of the names, regardless of the table that name is in
- one very big caveat - this query will keep returning errors like `Unknown column 'TableA.Name' in 'field list'`, if you're using MySQL / MariaDB. The solution in this case is to emulate the unsupported `FULL JOIN` (all of the data from A matched with all of the data from B, plus unmatched A and B data). For example, you could do it like this:

```
SELECT
    TableA.Name,
    TableA.Color,
    IFNULL(TableB.Fruit,"") AS Fruit
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB
    ON TableA.Name = TableB.Name
UNION
SELECT
    TableB.Name,
    IFNULL(TableA.Color,"") AS Color,
    TableB.Fruit
FROM TableB
LEFT JOIN TableA
    ON TableB.Name = TableA.Name
ORDER BY Name ASC
```

Note that this is using the `UNION` as is the first query, but here we're returning three columns, instead of two. Also, when retrieving the `Fruit` data from TableA, we're using `IFNULL(...)`. This is just for show - becase we know that the data **doesn't** exist in TableA, we can just say

```
"" AS Fruit
```

just so we could have the third column needed for the union, and in doing that, avoid the unnecessary checking (we know it won't be there). The same thing applies for retrieving the Color from TableA. So why did I use `IFNULL`? Just to show you how it works - `IFNULL` displays the value of the second argument, if the first one is NULL.

Please see [this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ex6yQZXsgS85iEj4BTz6sy/0) for examples and testing.